# How to get dropdown to work in puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape data from https://my.castlighthealth.com/corona-virus-testing-sites/

It has the dropdown for "STATE". When I click on an item it shows data on the right side.

I am trying to emulate same thing with puppeteer.js but even after selecting the element I can't see results on the window.

Here is my code

```
 const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const array = []
        const arrayVal = []
        var state = document.getElementById("state");
        let stateLength = state.options.length
        stateLengthI = stateLength
        for (let i = 1; i < stateLength; i++) {
            let value = state.options[i].innerHTML
            arrayVal.push(state.options[i].value)
            array.push({ state: value })
        }
        return arrayVal
    })


    for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        await page.select("#state", result[i]).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this script for you, and add node-fetch requirement to request results of a state selection

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()
    await page.goto('https://my.castlighthealth.com/corona-virus-testing-sites/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const array = []
        const arrayVal = []
        var state = document.getElementById("state");
        let stateLength = state.options.length
        stateLengthI = stateLength
        for (let i = 1; i < stateLength; i++) {
            let value = state.options[i].innerHTML
            arrayVal.push(state.options[i].value)
            array.push({ state: value })
        }
        return arrayVal
    })

    let bodySummary = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        await page.select("#state", result[i]).then( res => {
            fetch(`https://my.castlighthealth.com/corona-virus-testing-sites/data/result.php?state_for=${res[0]}&v=06042020925`)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(body => {
                bodySummary+= body
                if (i === 51) {
                    console.log(bodySummary)
                }
            })
        })
    }

})()
```

Comment: Thanks @Edi but all it is doing is to show html of those pages as raw text, I experimented with it before but it not usable for me.I was hoping to go through similar work flow as a normal user does.

Comment: Just want to know why the select doesn't work for this dropdown. I can find workarounds but my curiosity is getting the best of me. :P

Comment: The true select HTML element isn't the visible one. And the visible dropdown isn't easy enough to be controlled by Puppeteer, IMHO.